# Accidentally deleted my /bin folder?

Tags: linux

I was screwing around in a root terminal, and I accidentally deleted my entire `/bin` folder. Is this dangerous? What should I do to fix this?

```
root@laptop:/# ls -l /
total 80
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 11 19:10 boot
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root  3360 Oct 11 20:21 dev
drwxr-xr-x 123 root root  4096 Oct 12 10:08 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Dec 14  2012 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Oct 11 19:10 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Oct 11 18:48 initrd.img.old -> /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4096 Oct 11 18:54 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 11 18:48 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Oct 11 18:47 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 11 20:21 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 14  2012 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May  6 05:27 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 150 root root     0 Oct 11 18:54 proc
drwx------   4 root root  4096 Oct 11 20:40 root
drwxr-xr-x  17 root root   680 Oct 12 10:06 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 11 19:09 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun 10  2012 selinux
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May  6 05:27 srv
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Oct 11 18:54 sys
drwxrwxrwt  11 root root  4096 Oct 12 11:31 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Oct 11 18:51 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Oct 11 18:55 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    26 Oct 11 19:10 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    26 Oct 11 18:51 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
```

Answer (score 6):

Dangerous? Not any more - you already did the dangerous thing.

You just deleted the part of the system that has *essential* things that belong every system needs. According to [wikipedia's article on the FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure) /bin contains "Essential command binaries that need to be available in single user mode; for all users, e.g., cat, ls, cp." These are MASSIVELY important in some contexts.

Assuming you want to fix this, you *might* be able to copy over /bin from a running system - maybe off a livecd of the same version of your distro. I'm not *totally* sure this would work.

Nonetheless, while you're trying this, back up any essential files in case anything goes wrong. /etc/ /home and /var might be good ideas, as would /srv in distros that use it

Answer (score 4):

Yes, what you just did is quite an essential mistake, maybe comparable to deleting Program Files on Windows (if that's possible).

If you have another (virtual) machine around, you could try this quite decent and fast solution to this common problem:

**What do we need?**

- ssh, rsync, sudo should all still be available
- you should have a similar system reachable from your network (with 
  coreutils)

**Process:**

1. Copy the bin directory:

The '#' sign means, you should be root. Substituting '#' with "sudo" will do on most systems. On others, use "su".

> ```
> # rsync -rv <remote-login>@<remote-server>:/bin /
> ```

or

> ```
> # scp -rv <remote-login>@<remote-server>:/bin /
> ```

2. Then 'cd' to the /bin directory (which should work again now)

> ```
> # ln -s bash sh
> ```

This is important since most programs actually link to /bin/sh and many 
scripts have it in the shebang (#!) line. You should link to bash (for 
most people), or the shell you use (for those, who probably wouldn't 
delete the /bin directory anyway).

3. Update and upgrade from your repository (on Ubuntu and Debian)

> ```
> # aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade
> ```

or

> ```
> # apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
> ```

That should at least get you a working system. You should maybe 
reinstall coreutils and in general be vary of any problems. You should 
backup your data and be cautious.

Comment: Think about just posting your U&L answer here.  With the dead link, this answer is sort of useless.  When you have a few more rep over there, you can post this type of answer to the other question and link it back to the complete answer here.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest releases of some distributions, like Debian, files from the directories in `/` are merged into their respective counterparts in /usr, hence `/bin` and others are simple symlinks:

```
/bin → /usr/bin
/sbin → /usr/sbin
/lib → /usr/lib
/lib64 → /usr/lib64
```

If this is your case, you can simple recreate these symlinks using the rescue or live mode of your distro.

Answer (score 1):

I made this mistake too; it's an easier mistake to make than you might think.

Luckily in CentOS8 the */bin* directory is just a symbolic link to the */usr/bin* directory, so if all you've done is deleted the */bin* directory, then you could be in luck. Here is what I did to resolve it:

1. I didn't reboot.
   My system would be usable until the disk was reloaded.
2. I relinked the the */bin* directory to the */usr/bin* directory

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin /bin
```

3. Then I reinstalled ALL of the installed packages

```
sudo dnf list --installed | sed 's/|/ /' | awk '{print $1}' > installed_packages
sudo dnf -y reinstall $(cat installed_packages)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following and was able to recover my fully functional Ubuntu within 5 minutes.

1. Install a Copy of your Ubuntu (Same version which has crashed) into a pen-drive.
2. Run Ubuntu live mode with pendrive on your sick machine
3. Locate your crashed drive and mount it  from the "places" tab, in the very top-left corner of your machine.
4. Open terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>" and create a bin folder into the mounted drive using `sudo`, i.e. `sudo mkdir /media/bin`
5. Copy all the bin files from your live session to victim device, with `sudo`, i.e. `sudo cp /bin/* /media/bin`
6. Restart, it may show some message to update your firmwares (or other messages) just ignore for while and login.